# Assign google drive video caption tracks using Google App script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to use Google App Script to upload/assign on a video in my Google Drive. Is there any API to do this. I already put subtitles (caption tracks) & videos in same directory  Google Drive. I don't want to repeatedly set subtitle for each videos.

Thank you for any help!!!